# How to copy from HOST to CONTAINER while within container

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile, cp

I am sorry for taking up your time.

I have a local docker setup and I want to copy files from my local host to my container.
But the thing is that I need a command that I can use WHILE i am inside the container.

To explain the situation further: I executed "docker exec -it CONTAINERNAME bash" to enter my container,
and now I am on /var/www/html
and I need to find a way to copy a file/folder from my local environment into that container.

Reason: I am currently writing a dockerfile which automates the process of setting things up. I need that very specific command because a Dockerfile RUN-command can only be executed while inside the container.

What I tried:

"docker cp" is a good command to use when I am outside the container but it doesn't work while in the container.

"DOCKERFILE COPY" might do the trick but I need a general shell command to double check if it really does what it is supposed to do. I must be able to reproduce the same process of my Dockerfile via manually executing the commands one by one.

Once again, I apologize for my inability to solve this problem by myself. My inexperience has caused me nothing but trouble.

Edit: I am using a Win10 64bit OS with dual monitor setup and a lefthanded mouse. My keyboard, albeit old, should possess all the necessary keys to replicate any essential keyboard-shortcuts if required. All my drivers are installed and updated.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: You can mount the directory on host to your container and then access files on host during runtime. https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: I thank you two kindly for your help. I have now included volumes that should sync between local storage and container storage. I am now attempting to it in this way: First, "docker-compose up and down" to sync up volumes. Second, "docker build" to utilize the volumes in order to do my commands, third, another "docker-compose up" to finally start it with all configurations complete.

Answer (score 0):

When you build an image you need to put there everything you need for a normal work of your container. You shouldn't copy files from the host once your image is built. You might use volumes as a common storage for both the host and the container but I don't think this is your case.

Until this is not totally clear what you do I'd suggest to prepare all the data you need and put it within docker context. Then build an image. You also may find `docker-compose` useful as, at least, it helps separately define the context and the path to your dockerfile if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using "docker-compose up --build" in order build my image prior to deploying it and that was my mistake. I should have used "docker build . -f path/to/Dockerfile" instead to build it and then deploying it with docker-compose. This is also the reason why my "DOCKERFILE COPY" commands didn't work because all these instructions are relative to where I executed my build command. I have seen the errors of my ways. I am one step closer to achieving my goals. Bless you.